# Как менять цвет svg иконки при наведении?

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg

Как через `:hover` менять цвет svg иконки?

Comment: в том то и дело что fill не роботает T_T

Answer (score 4):

Можно [использовать css-свойство `fill`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/fill/):

```
svg:hover {
  fill: цвет;
}
```

Сниппет:

```css
svg:hover {
  fill: teal;
}

svg {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z"/>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```